# How can I ask for the username and password only the first time I need it?

Tags: perl

I know basics of scripting but not expert. Hence i needed your advice.

In one of my perl script, i have a subroutine which calls user to enter their username and password. I am able to achieve that by using Readmode. But, I have a requirement to call the username and password everytime the subroutine is called.

```
sub connect{
        my $user = "";
        my $pwd = "";

        print "\n  Please enter username:";
        $user=<>;
        chomp($user);

        print "  Please enter password:";
        ReadMode 'noecho';
        $pwd = <STDIN>;
        chomp $pwd;
.
.
.
```

And I am calling this subroutine named "connect" 3 times in my script. So everytime, this subroutine is called, it prompts to enter the credentials 3 times. I am thinking if there is a way to store the value of the username and password into variable and call these variables everytime the subroutine "connect" is called.

Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using a Perl newer than 5.10, you can use the [`state`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/state) feature.

```
use feature 'state';

sub connect {
    state $user, $pwd;

    unless (defined $user and defined $pwd) {
        print "\n  Please enter username:";
        $user=<>;
        chomp($user);

        print "  Please enter password:";
        ReadMode 'noecho';
        $pwd = <STDIN>;
        chomp $pwd;
    }

    # use $user / $pwd as normal
    #   ...
}
```

`$user` and `$pwd` will retain their values between calls to this sub.